# Upvote on Triage "Looks Ok" consensus

Tags: discussion, upvotes, triage, community-user

Every reviewer on Triage knows that when they press the "Looks OK" button and there is a consensus, a screen suggests to upvote the question. AFAIK, the last reviewer see this screen, (maybe the two last reviewers I don't know).

I wondering if a possibility of an automatic upvote (by Community♦) was analyzed under design phase. (Instead of actual manual upvote given by reviewers)

I guess this was considered and was discarded.

IMO, just one upvote gives better chances to get a better answer (or any answer at all). And considering that the consensus is "Looks OK", this feature could induce the asker to put a bit more effort. (?)

Comment: The plan seems to be that a question that doesn't "look ok" will not even show up on the homepage at all. So in that sense, the upvote will not be necessary in separating out the good questions. The truly good questions will be upvoted by users.

Comment: @Mysticial your statement leaves my statement useless

Comment: To sum it up: "okay" is not "good". "Okay" is "not terrible". Upvotes are generally reserved for "good" questions (for individual definitions of good).

Comment: @ChrisHayes, one upvote in a question is nothing. Please do no hyper-valuate an upvote. It's just a piece in a biggest game ;)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by pretty much any of that, but if you're upvoting out of pity and not because a question is actually good and brings value to the site, you're probably voting on the wrong basis.

Comment: @ChrisHayes no no no *upvoting out of pity*. I usually upvote and star a question just to know the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm glad you asked!

I originally thought it would be expeditious to just *automatically* upvote everything that ended up triaged as Looks OK, and automatically downvote everything that got tossed the other way. Both as a signal to the author, and as a way of more easily tracking the outcome of triage within the system.

Fortunately, I'm fortunate to work with several people possessing some measure of sanity, and on this occasion they were gracious enough to share it.

Voting borders on sacrosanct within the system. We're *very* reluctant to create votes except in response to a direct signal from a user. Even the handful of situations where automatic votes *are* created (in response to Spam, Offensive and Very Low Quality flags) they're still tied directly to an explicit action on the part of a user, and automatically revoked if that action appears to have been the result of a misunderstanding.

That said, you're correct that an upvote on a brand-new post can greatly increase its chances of being well-received. They also tend to provide positive feedback to the author, which doesn't *necessarily* encouraging further positive participation but also doesn't *discourage* it, while the lack of any response does. Therefore, it's advantageous to everyone if good questions are quickly upvoted... and not-so-good questions are *ignored*.

Thus, the voting UI. It's shown to the *last* reviewer - the person whose review establishes a consensus of Looks OK within the review system and dequeues the question.

Here are some quick statistics on how this has played out so far:

```
Name               Tasks PctTotal PctUpvoted PctDownvoted 
------------------ ----- -------- ---------- ------------ 
Looks Good         7245  36.94 %  24.96 %    0.22 %       
Should Be Improved 10573 53.91 %  0.13 %     1.02 %       
Unsalvageable      1793  9.14 %   0.00 %     6.08 %
```

Note that the votes counted there are only those cast by the last reviewer. Note also that we *don't* prompt the last reviewer to vote in situations where the consensus is other than Looks OK, although they can still do so by either opening the normal question page or navigating *back* to the completed review page.

As for tracking the outcome of review within the system... We already have an alternate "score" that can be utilized for this: the automatically generated "quality score" that sends things into review in the first place! Going forward, we plan to just modify this in response to review and other actions, so that it can be used across the board to direct questions in the proper direction.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that Unsalvageable is only 9% of the total It "feels" like it should be closer to 50%. That said, many of the questions in the triage *can* be salvaged, but nobody is ever going to spend the effort to do so.

Comment: Right. It turns out the biggest quality problem isn't questions that *stink to high heaven* so much as those that are just a little bit ripe. This is what we've been struggling with for so long in close review: an awful lot of questions that don't really need to be closed, but just need to go away.