# Triage suggests upvoting, but upvote button is not present in triage

Tags: bug, triage

When triaging a question, it looks like this for me (no up- or downvote buttons):

[image]

However, i get the advise to upvote the questions:

[image]

The problem is that i could no upvote, since the button was not there!

Comment: If you look under the banner there, where it asked you to upvote in your second screenshot, you'll see the voting arrows. :) Pretty sure those are supposed to work on that screen.

Comment: @Kendra: you reacted to soon. The problem is that those buttons are only present when the upvote message is showing, but not during regular triage. You can only perform triage and then proceed to the next question (screenshot 1).

Comment: That's by-design. Let me find the link for it.

Comment: @Kendra: then why do i get the suggestion to upvote, when it is not possible in the triage queue?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that only the deciding vote (for Looks Ok) sees this dialog.  Basically, you are only seeing that dialog when a question has successfully left triage in one piece.  After all, until multiple people have decided on the question's quality, it would be silly to prematurely give an option to vote on it.

Comment: If you are going to upvote, you do it on the page that encourages you to upvote. Otherwise, that's not the point of triage. The point is to quickly identify where a question falls, and send it where it needs to go. If you are the third "Looks OK" review, you are encouraged to upvote the question to give it a good start. Otherwise, voting should not be your concern. [This post covers it a bit.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280593/2607247) I'll look for a better explanation at home.

Comment: @Kendra: that makes it a bit clearer. I already wondered what triggered that suggestion. I was getting frustrated with nagging for upvotes when i could not actually vote in triage. Perhaps the wording of the suggestion should include an explanation why i'm seeing it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here for me is not specifically that voting buttons aren't available during reviewing (that's the same for other review queues). It's really the message that's confusing:

> Please remember to **upvote** clear, useful, well-researched questions to encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!

"Please remember"? I didn't forget! This message seems to imply that I'm too grudging with my upvotes, or that I forgot something. That's not the case. It's simply that it wasn't possible to vote.

I suggest changing the message to something like:

> Please **upvote** this question if you think it's clear, useful and well-researched to encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!

Alternatively (but that would be more difficult, I suppose), a button could be added *iff* the user has a deciding role: "Looks OK - upvote" next to "Looks OK".

Or, a simple alert could show up when you click "Looks OK" and you had a deciding role: "Do you also want to upvote this question?" - yes / no or OK / cancel.

Comment: +1 agreed the word "remember" implies you've forgotten to do something. The fact the page redraws and the upvote icon shakes also makes it feel like you're getting told off.