# Why is there no facility to vote in Triage?

Tags: discussion, triage

I come across quite a few bad questions in Triage. If I'm marking them as "unsalvageable" or sometimes even "should be improved", I'll probably want to vote them down as well, but there's no facility to do this directly in Triage. Slightly cheerier flipside, if the question "Looks OK", I may want to vote up.

I know it's just a matter of opening the question in another tab, but why disable voting in the first place?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Voting in review has generally proven to be a pretty bad idea. In triage, where each question is shown to *at least* 3 different people, it would be a mess: half-way decent questions coming out with 3 upvotes while great questions that never needed to be triaged in the first place get 1 or none, lousy questions getting massively downvoted within seconds of being posted while the author struggles to fix his errors, etc.

We've experimented with voting in the past, both in the first iteration of the review system and in the First Posts / Late Answers queues; results have ranged from mediocre to horror.

We [briefly discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280590/upvote-on-triage-looks-ok-consensus/280593#280593) tying *automatic* votes to review consensus in Triage, but opted to go a different route to avoid skewing voting even that much; if you do care enough to vote (or edit, or answer...) it's easy enough to get to the full question page, and if you don't... then don't.

Comment: In this case, the buttons for upvote and downvote should not be displayed, or a warning should be shown. As it is done now, we could think that there is a bug with the buttons