# In Triage, if a question's consensus is "Looks OK", the GUI suggests I can vote on it after the review, but I cannot

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage

So this is *incredibly* frustrating.  For those who still insist that this is a dupe:

- The dupe explains why there is no facility to vote in Triage.
- My question concerns two portions - there **is** a facility to vote in Triage **if you are the last person to vote "Looks OK"**, and **the consensus of the review is "Looks OK".**
- Even *if* we couldn't vote in Triage, the fact that the GUI to do so appears **at all** is a bug in my eyes.  Don't give us functionality we can't actually use.

Original bug report below.

---

I've recently completed a review in which I felt that the question looked OK.  I went to upvote it in the Triage window, but I can't - clicking the arrows accomplishes nothing.

Ironically I can click to see the vote totals.

[image]

Seems like a bug to me, given that the option to vote is being denied.  Note that I'm not seeing any errors in the console, almost as if the JavaScript call is being stubbed out here.

[Another question on this matter exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283673/why-is-there-no-facility-to-vote-in-triage), but the impression I get from that (almost) four-year old question and answer is that the option to see a vote total isn't even presented to the reviewer, let alone the ability to vote.

It seems to me that if it *were* the case that one couldn't vote from Triage, then seeing the buttons and dialog which indicates that you *can* vote from Triage are superfluous and should be removed.  That would make this question fundamentally different from the supposed dupe.

Comment: @Servy:  Would that dupe imply that the vote buttons simply *don't* appear or that they appear and are disabled?  I read that and interpreted the dupe as the buttons simply didn't appear.

Comment: I don't see anything there either way to indicate whether the buttons are intended to be there and disabled or missing entirely.  If this is you saying that, given that voting is not supported, you don't think the buttons should be showing up at all, then I guess I didn't really get that out of your question.  You said you wanted to be able to vote, this explains why you can't.

Comment: @Servy:  I disagree.  It seems the context of that dupe is that you aren't even shown a screen where you would have the option *to* vote.  Here, I'm shown the option but cannot click on either arrow, yet can click on the vote counts *as if I could vote*.  Not convinced the dupe applies.

Comment: Where in the question does it say that there are no buttons?  It says that you can't vote.  And *your* question is asking why you can't vote, not why the buttons show up, which is exactly answered by the duplicate.  Had you asked why the vote buttons show up when voting is restricted, then yes, that question wouldn't cover it.

Comment: @Servy: The dupe doesn't apply, since I know that I have on many occasions voted (as the last Looks OK reviewer) on Triaged questions from within the queue. In fact, [the Triage FAQ still mentions up- or down-voting appropriately as the last reviewer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674)! The dupe does not mention this at all, implying that Shog did not consider it to be relevant (since, presumably, the question is referring to the more common case where the review is still ongoing). See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280593, also by Shog, which introduces the feature.

Comment: @Servy I just came to meta to report the same bug. After enough votes are made that a post "Looks Ok", it gives you the option to vote on it. This has been a feature for a long time. I only noticed this morning that clicking the up/down votes don't do anything. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21761308

Comment: This still does not appear to have received much attention.

Comment: Same problem here (Chrome, 71.0.3578.98, Win 10). This is quite frustrating indeed.

Comment: Same here. The up/down arrow icons have a selection effect (a border shows when cursor is not on them) and show the usual tooltip: *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)"*. Together with the review-reminder *"Please remember to upvote..."*, this is really frustrating. I seem to remember this worked in the past.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry, I overlooked this; it's been broken since the day before you posted the report. Fix pending.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the report - somehow I missed this back in December, so we went 4 months without voting in Triage; I'd actually noticed the huge falloff in votes coming from Triage reviews, but hadn't actually tested it.

Clearly I should... upvote stuff more?

Anyway, the root cause here was changes to the markup made to improve accessibility for the voting buttons. Along with those changes, the class names used to identify that area of the page were altered, and thus... The review script stopped wiring up any behavior to those buttons. The fix then was no more involved than changing `div.vote` to `.js-voting-container`.

With this live, voting is once again possible. Thanks for your patience here!